# Expression.Lambda returns with "The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Why?

Tags: c#, linq

I have been over at Jeremy to "borrow" som very nice code that more or less acts as dynamic-linq. https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/dynamically-build-linq-expressions/

I have made som small changes. I would like to evalute predicates based on Regex. The product of an Expression.Lambda looks like this.

```
        .Where(d => new  List<string> { "P1101", "P1102"}
            .Contains(d.PntName) | Regex.IsMatch(
            input: d.PntName, 
            pattern: "^A.*"))
```

I get the following error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DataTransaction>
    .Where(d => List<string> { "P1101", "P1102", }
        .Contains(d.PntName) | Regex.IsMatch(
        input: d.PntName, 
        pattern: "^A.*"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

*** Update ***

The problematic part of the query is being produced at runtime. I am setting the following MethodInfo

```
typeof(Regex).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
     .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Regex.IsMatch)
          && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
```

Is there somewhere to declare that the method should omit the names?

**** Full Code ****

```
Program.cs
            using (var context = new DataTransactionContext(optionsWithLog))
            {
                var count = await context.DbDataTransactions.CountAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Verified insert count: {count}.");
                Console.WriteLine("Parsing expression...");
                var parser = new JsonExpressionParser();
                var predicate = parser.ParseExpressionOf<DataTransaction>(
                    JsonDocument.Parse(
                        await File.ReadAllTextAsync("dataDatabaseRules.json")));
                Console.WriteLine("Retrieving from database...");
                var query = context.DbDataTransactions.Where(predicate);
                    //.OrderBy(t => t.PntNo);
                var results = await query.ToListAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved {results.Count}");
                Console.WriteLine("Sample:");
                Console.WriteLine(results[0]);
            }
```

ExpressionParser

```
public class JsonExpressionParser
{
    private const string StringStr = "string";

    private readonly string BooleanStr = nameof(Boolean).ToLower();
    private readonly string Number = nameof(Number).ToLower();
    private readonly string In = nameof(In).ToLower();
    private readonly string And = nameof(And).ToLower();
    private readonly string Contains = nameof(Contains).ToLower();

    //Method construction
    private readonly MethodInfo MethodContains = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains)
                        && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    private readonly MethodInfo PerformMyMeth =
    //    typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    typeof(Regex).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Regex.IsMatch)
                    && m.GetParameters().Length == 2); //Sætter antallet af parametre for Regex


    private delegate Expression Binder(Expression left, Expression right);

    private Expression ParseTree<T>(
        JsonElement condition,
        ParameterExpression parm)
    {
        Expression left = null;

        //AND OR
        var gate = condition.GetProperty(nameof(condition)).GetString();
        
        JsonElement rules = condition.GetProperty(nameof(rules));

        //Binder > Short hand for Binary Expression
        Binder binder = gate == And ? (Binder)Expression.And : Expression.Or;

        Expression bind(Expression left, Expression right) =>
            left == null ? right : binder(left, right);

        foreach (var rule in rules.EnumerateArray())
        {
            if (rule.TryGetProperty(nameof(condition), out JsonElement check))
            {
                var right = ParseTree<T>(rule, parm);
                left = bind(left, right);
                continue;
            }

            string @operator = rule.GetProperty(nameof(@operator)).GetString();     //eg. IN
            string type = rule.GetProperty(nameof(type)).GetString();               //eg. string
            string field = rule.GetProperty(nameof(field)).GetString();             //eg. PntName
            
            JsonElement value = rule.GetProperty(nameof(value));                    //værdien
            
            //The expression constant has to be compared to some property. The code in the next snippet creates a property expression.
            var property = Expression.Property(parm, field);
            
            if (@operator == In)
            {

                //Contains call that we build ealier
                var contains = MethodContains.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

                object val = value.EnumerateArray().Select(e => e.GetString())
                    .ToList();

                var right = Expression.Call(
                    contains,
                    Expression.Constant(val),
                    property);
                left = bind(left, right);
            }
            else if(@operator == Contains)
            {


                object val = (type == StringStr || type == BooleanStr) ?
                    (object)value.GetString() : value.GetDecimal();

                var toCompare = Expression.Constant(val);
                var right = Expression.Call(PerformMyMeth, property, toCompare);

                left = bind(left, right);
            }
            else
            {
                object val = (type == StringStr || type == BooleanStr) ?
                    (object)value.GetString() : value.GetDecimal();
                var toCompare = Expression.Constant(val);
                var right = Expression.Equal(property, toCompare);

                left = bind(left, right);
            }
        }

        return left;
    }

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseExpressionOf<T>(JsonDocument doc)
    {
        //En oprettelse af en Expression sker ved hjælp af static factory method kald.
        // ParameterExpression, en reference til en Lambda expression
        var itemExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        Console.WriteLine("Item expression: " + itemExpression.ToString());

        var conditions = ParseTree<T>(doc.RootElement, itemExpression);

        if (conditions.CanReduce)
        {
            conditions = conditions.ReduceAndCheck();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Conditions: " + conditions.ToString());

        var query = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(conditions, itemExpression);
        return query;
    }

    public Func<T, bool> ParsePredicateOf<T>(JsonDocument doc)
    {
        var query = ParseExpressionOf<T>(doc);
        return query.Compile();
    }
```

Comment: How are you invoking the reflected method?

Comment: _"The problematic part of the query is being produced at runtime."_ - please show the exact code which does that.

Comment: Is your question about building the expression-tree without the arg-names or anything different I did not catch? We don't know where the names come from, so you should provide the code that produces that expression-tree, probably.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I is about building the expression tree without arg-names

Comment: then you should show the code that creates the expression-tree.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain

Comment: @GuruStron I added the code. I also updated the error message.

Comment: Acutally It might be fine with the arguments. It might just be Linqpad that cant handle the named arguments

Comment: I can't see where you use `PerformMyMeth`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Thanks for your patience. I deleted to much in the post. I have updated the code snippets.

Comment: The error you posted comes from EF Core, not LINQ. EF Core, and all ORMs, translate LINQ queries to SQL. You can't generate SQL that contains client-side calls and functions like `Regex.IsMatch`.

Comment: Try testing the built expression against an in memory `IEnumerable` (converted to an `IQueryable`) and see if it works. As @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, `EFCore` would not be able to generate `SQL` for the given expression.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank for your comment, I will look into Contains and StartsWith and Endswith and see if that can be a part of the solution.

Comment: @WBuck so I did test it against an in memory datastructure and it works flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: When building `Expression` trees for use with LINQ to databases, you can always test with an explicit, manual query matching what you are trying to do, e.g. if you do a query `context.DbDataTransactions.Where(d => new  List<string> { "P1101", "P1102"}.Contains(d.PntName) | Regex.IsMatch(input: d.PntName, pattern: "^A.*"))` what do you get? LINQ to databases (depending on version) has serious limitations on what can be translated to SQL. LINQPad is a good tool for testing queries and viewing how the compiler translates code into `Expression` trees.

Comment: Your particular Regex looks like it could be replaced with `d.PntName.StartsWith("A")` - note that whether the comparison to "A" is case-sensitive depends on the collation assigned to the column in the database.

Comment: @NetMage true, but I have many very complex regular expressions that needs to filter a list

Comment: You don't say what database or LINQ provider you are using, but if it is SQL Server and EF Core you can use the `EF.Functions.Like` method with T-SQL regular expressions.

Comment: @NetMage yes true, I think LIKE is a bit to narrow for my purpose. I like Regex better as it give me more granularity. Is it possible to use EF core with Redis?

Comment: @KN I don't know about redis. However, I think you misunderstood about `LIKE`. With SQL Server and T-SQL, the `LIKE` operator supports regular expression matching.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function as non-named arguments

```cs
.Where(d => new  List<string> { "P1101", "P1102"}
            .Contains(d.PntName) | Regex.IsMatch(
                d.PntName, 
                "^A.*"))
```

Comment: great suggestion :) The question have been updated with additionally  context.